Distance-to-safe-win metric
Assume you have an endgame position which can be won in exactly three ways:

DTM 51...only OTB it isn't won because of the 50 move rule
DTZ 30, the resulting position won in 40 moves
DTZ 40, the resulting position won in 20 moves

Thus the optimal metric would choose the third variant.
In a computer chess mag from 20 years ago, I read "There is no tablebase
with this metric yet." (The "why" is obvious for me - you'd have to total
over several phases, and it is unclear if the number of phases stays
so small that move sum optimization can be handled.)
Is this old news now, i.e. a metric "Shortest win under 50 move rule" exists? (I looked into Wiki, only DTM/DTC/DTZ are mentioned.)
